# Force cmake to link shared library with static library without mentioning a specific target

Tags: cmake, static-linking

I am trying to make a shared library linked with a static version of librt. Currently I am doing this:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
ADD_LIBRARY(memtrace SHARED memtrace.c)
ADD_LIBRARY(lib_real_time STATIC IMPORTED)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(lib_real_time PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.a)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(memtrace lib_real_time)
```

But I do not want to specify the path like this. Since librt is always in standard paths, I'd rather have cmake find it. Like in gcc I would only specify -lrt.
When I try to do this using this cmake file:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
ADD_LIBRARY(memtrace SHARED memtrace.c)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(memtrace rt)
```

It will link memtrace with the dynamic version of librt which is not what I want!!

How can I link with the static version of librt without mentioning its full path?

Comment: `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(memtrace rt.a)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Make it an answer if you want the credit!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To link with the static version of the library, just add ".a" extension to it's name:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(memtrace rt.a)
```

Comment: Don't do this, there are platforms where the static libraries do _not_ have the `.a` extension. Windows, for example :-)

Comment: @user465139 how can we selectivelly link to shared or static?