# Creating CMake executables using multiple libraries

Tags: linux, cmake, static-libraries, static-linking

I have succeeded in creating static libraries from my source files using CMake. Now I need to create quite a few executables using these libraries. I have read the CMake examples and attempted to duplicate what they had listed but did not seem to work. I am receiving the error:

***Linking CXX executable ../../build/bin/discoveryService
armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++: CMakeFiles/discoveryService.dir/discoveryService.cpp.o: linker input file unused because linking not done***

Here is a quick overview of my directory structure. Each directory creates a static library from the source files included in that directory. Most directories also need to generate executables which rely on libraries within the **633/arm** directory:

[image: 633/arm File Structure]

Here is my original Makefile:

```
$(shell ../../build_environment.sh)

BIN = ../../build/bin
TMP = build

BUILD_DEF = -DBUILD=$(BUILD_VERSION) -DBUILD_DATE=$(BUILD_DATE)

# these files are captured from the DSPLink Sample build directory (and the named  changed)
# they contain the appropriate includes and flags to build a dsplink application.
DSPLINK_INCLUDES = $(shell cat ../dsplink_config/dsplink_includes.txt)
DSPLINK_FLAGS = $(shell cat ../dsplink_config/dsplink_flags.txt)
DSPLINK_DEFINES = $(shell cat ../dsplink_config/dsplink_defines.txt)
DSPLINK_LIBS =      $(DSPLINK_PACKAGE_DIR)/dsplink/gpp/export/BIN/Linux/OMAPL1XX/RELEASE/dsplink.lib


#Our project variables
INCLUDE= -I. -I../framework -I../flagDictionary -I../logging -I../../dsp/include -      I../modbus -I../expat

TOOLCHAIN = /OMAP-L137/timesys/SDK/omapl137_evm/toolchain/bin
#TOOLCHAIN = ${FACTORY_DIR}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/toolchain/bin
PLATFORM=armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi

#Compile Options
CC=$(TOOLCHAIN)/$(PLATFORM)-g++
LINKER=$(TOOLCHAIN)/$(PLATFORM)-g++
CFLAGS+=$(BUILD_DEF) $(INCLUDE)
DEBUG =  

#list of things to compile.
FW_BUILD_DIR=../framework/build
LOG_BUILD_DIR=../logging/build
XML_BUILD_DIR=../expat/build
MODBUS_BUILD_DIR=../modbus/build
FLAG_DICT_BUILD_DIR=../flagDictionary/build

CORE_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS= $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/application.o \
                $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/arguments.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/com.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/memoryManagerBase.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/memoryManager.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/lockManager.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/stopWatch.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/controlCom.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/status.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/paths.o \
        $(LOG_BUILD_DIR)/subsystemLogMasks.o \
        $(LOG_BUILD_DIR)/logger.o

# removed utils.o from CORE

NET_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS=  $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/message.o \
            $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/chunk.o \
            $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/multicastSocket.o \
            $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/serverSocket.o \
            $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/socket.o \
        $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/tcpReader.o

CONF_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS= $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/configuration.o \
            $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/editConfig.o \
            $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/parseConfig.o \
            $(FW_BUILD_DIR)/xpath.o \
        $(XML_BUILD_DIR)/xmlparse.o \
        $(XML_BUILD_DIR)/xmlrole.o \
        $(XML_BUILD_DIR)/xmltok.o

MODBUS_OBJECTS=     $(MODBUS_BUILD_DIR)/modbus.o \
        $(MODBUS_BUILD_DIR)/modbusFacade.o

MODBUS_RTU_OBJECTS= $(MODBUS_BUILD_DIR)/modbus.o \
        $(MODBUS_BUILD_DIR)/rtuFacade.o

FLAG_DICT_OBJECTS=  $(FLAG_DICT_BUILD_DIR)/flagEntry.o \
        $(FLAG_DICT_BUILD_DIR)/flagDictionary.o


OBJECTS = discoveryService.o \
  httpService.o \
  modbusService.o \
  streamingService.o \
  trendMap.o \
  trendService.o \
  tripBuffer.o \
  modbusRTUService.o \
  tripReader.o
EXES = discoveryService httpService modbusService streamingService trendService    tripReader modbusRTUService cmprXfr

all: $(OBJECTS) $(EXES)

.c.o:
mkdir -p build
$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(DSPLINK_INCLUDES) $(DSPLINK_FLAGS) $(DSPLINK_DEFINES) $(DEBUG)       -o $(TMP)/$@ $< 

.cpp.o:
mkdir -p build
$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(DSPLINK_INCLUDES) $(DSPLINK_FLAGS) $(DSPLINK_DEFINES) $(DEBUG)   -o $(TMP)/$@ $< 

discoveryService: $(FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) discoveryService.o
$(LINKER) -lpthread -lc -o $(BIN)/$@ $(DSPLINK_LIBS) build/discoveryService.o    $(FLAG_DICT_OBJECTS) $(CORE_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) $(NET_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS)    $(CONF_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS)

httpService: $(FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) httpService.o
$(LINKER) -lpthread -lc -o $(BIN)/$@ $(DSPLINK_LIBS) build/httpService.o   $(FLAG_DICT_OBJECTS) $(CORE_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS)

modbusService: $(FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) modbusService.o
$(LINKER) -lpthread -lc -o $(BIN)/$@ $(DSPLINK_LIBS) build/modbusService.o  $(FLAG_DICT_OBJECTS) $(CORE_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) $(MODBUS_OBJECTS) $(NET_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS)

modbusRTUService: $(FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) modbusRTUService.o
$(LINKER) -lpthread -lc -o $(BIN)/$@ $(DSPLINK_LIBS) build/modbusRTUService.o      $(FLAG_DICT_OBJECTS) $(CORE_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) $(MODBUS_RTU_OBJECTS)

cmprXfr: $(FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) cmprXfr.o
$(LINKER) -lpthread -lc -o $(BIN)/$@ $(DSPLINK_LIBS) build/cmprXfr.o     $(CORE_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) $(NET_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) $(MODBUS_OBJECTS) $(FLAG_DICT_OBJECTS)

streamingService: $(FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) streamingService.o
$(LINKER) -lpthread -lc -o $(BIN)/$@ $(DSPLINK_LIBS) build/streamingService.o  build/tripBuffer.o $(FLAG_DICT_OBJECTS) $(CORE_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) $(NET_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS)     $(CONF_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS)

trendService: $(FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) trendService.o trendMap.o
$(LINKER) -lpthread -lc -o $(BIN)/$@ $(DSPLINK_LIBS) build/trendService.o build/trendMap.o $(FLAG_DICT_OBJECTS) $(CORE_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) $(NET_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS)  $(CONF_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS)

tripReader: $(FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) tripReader.o
$(LINKER) -lpthread -lc -o $(BIN)/$@ $(DSPLINK_LIBS) build/tripReader.o  build/tripBuffer.o $(FLAG_DICT_OBJECTS) $(CORE_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) $(NET_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) $(CONF_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS)

USBstreamingService: $(FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS) USBstreamingService.o
$(LINKER) -lpthread -lc -o $(BIN)/$@ $(DSPLINK_LIBS) build/USBstreamingService.o $(FLAG_DICT_OBJECTS) $(CORE_FRAMEWORK_OBJECTS)
```

Here is my top-level CMakeList.txt

```
INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(633.CMake)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
#this one not so much
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
SET(FACTORY_CURRENT /home/projects/OMAP-L137/timesys/factory-current)
SET(DSPLINK_PATH ${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-     1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01)
SET(DSPLINK_PACKAGE_DIR ${FACTORY_CURRENT}/${DSPLINK_PATH})
SET(TOOLCHAIN_LOC ${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-   uclibcgnueabi/toolchain/bin)

#read file into variable 'defines'
file(READ ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/dsplink_config/dsplink_defines.txt defines) 
#turn space separation into CMake list
string(REPLACE " " ";" defines "${defines}") 
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${defines})

# specify the cross compiler
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_LOC}/armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_LOC}/armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++)
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -c")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS})

# where is the target environment 
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /home/projects/OMAP-L137/timesys/factory-current)
SET(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR /home/chrisk/633/)

# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/build/bin)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(arm)
```

And here is my CMakeList.txt in the directory ***633/arm/communications*** where my source files are located.

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/framework     ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/flagDictionary ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/logging ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dsp/include ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/modbus ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/expat)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-  uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/inc/usr)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/home/projects/OMAP-L137/timesys/factory-20120925-633/build_armv5l-  timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/inc/usr)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/home/projects/OMAP-L137/timesys/factory-20120925-633/build_armv5l-  timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/inc/sys/Linux)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/inc)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/inc/usr)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/inc/sys/Linux)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/inc/sys/Linux/2.6.18)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/src/samples/loop)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/src/samples/loop/Linux)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/src/samples/loop/Linux/2.6.18)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/BUILD/INCLUDE/USER)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-  1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/export/INCLUDE/Linux/OMAPL1XX/internal)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${FACTORY_DIR}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/toolchain/include)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${FACTORY_CURRENT}/build_armv5l-timesys-linux-uclibcgnueabi/DSPLink-1_65_01/DSPLink-   1_65_01/dsplink/gpp/export/BIN/Linux/OMAPL1XX/RELEASE/dsplink.lib)

SET(communications_SOURCES 
discoveryService.cpp
httpService.cpp
modbusRTUService.cpp
modbusService.cpp
streamingService.cpp
trendMap.cpp
trendService.cpp
tripBuffer.cpp
tripReader.cpp
)

ADD_LIBRARY(communications ${communications_SOURCES})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/flagDictionary/libflagDictionary.a)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/framework/libframework.a)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/arm/communications/libcommunications.a)
         TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${DSPLINK_PACKAGE_DIR}/dsplink/gpp/export/BIN/Linux/OMAPL1XX/RELEASE/dsplink.lib)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(discoveryService discoveryService.cpp)
```

I used the **ADD_EXECUTABLE** as shown in the [CMake Tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html) and tried using **TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES** to link the libraries. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would something like `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(discoveryService communications)` after the `ADD_EXECUTABLE(..)` do the trick ? See the definition of the function : `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(target library1 library2)` http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/target_link_libraries.html . See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632266/force-cmake-to-link-shared-library-with-static-library-without-mentioning-a-spec . Try also to modify the other `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` : the target is `communications`.

Comment: In TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES target name is missing as first argument.once check that.